# How do I return a text string from the OpenCPU that respects the line breaks?

Tags: javascript, opencpu

I am trying to print a screenshot from the `OpenCPU`, which returns everything in a group and does not accept the line breaks.

When using `console.log()` I get the open cpc url with the perfect line breaks, but in the index I get out

This is my code;

```
function (data) {
    var statResultsLink = resultsUrlPrefix + data.toString().match(/.+\/stdout/m),
    chartLink = resultsUrlPrefix + data.toString().match(/.+\/graphics\/[1]/m);

    // Add statistical (textual) results to results div
    $('#results').append("<br/>");
    $('<div/>', {
        id: 'statResults'
    }).appendTo('#results');

    $(document).ready(function() {                                 
        $("#statResults").load(statResultsLink);
    });

    // Add charts results to results div
    $('#results').append("<br/>");
    $('<img/>', {
        id: 'chartResults',
        src: chartLink
    }).appendTo('#results');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a pre code tags to your text div to  automagically break the R output

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how I did it. Thank you very much

Comment: $('#results').append("<br/>");
$('<div/>', {
id: 'statResults'
}).appendTo('#results #pre');